# Laravel 5 basic auth

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I am dealing with a situation which is causes me a lot of confusion.  My boss has a web server setup with very simple HTTP auth ( which pop-up a login panel asking for `username` and `password`) after the login you have access to number of application which is running behind the web server.

The application I am developing ( using laravel & angular) supposed to function the same way. I have a database running behind laravel, but doesn't have `users` table. The `users` table is coupled with web server (Apache) which validates the `user` with his `password` before getting anywhere. The question is: How I might go about getting the user into the Laravel environment (validated)? Do I need to use LDAP instead of eloquent for the validation? or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Laravel supports basic http auth from the box: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#http-basic-authentication
Also, Laravel's default installation contains `users` table migration. So just run migrations and implement basic auth like it said in docs.

Comment: @Maxim Lanin Thanks for reply. But this is not the case. I know laravel has that functionality. But I do not want any `users` table behind laravel. Apache has to that and it take cares of the validation at the first layer ( so to speak) Laravel app comes on second layer after the user is validated. The only thing I have to do in laravel is to fetch the validated user ( coming form the first layer).  I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Would just changing the table `users` to your specific table do the job?

Comment: @BharatGeleda I am not sure I understand your suggested approach. Could you please be more specific. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only idea I have is to make redirect via apache after user was authenticated. Try to play around with this example:

```
<Location /auth/basic>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Zone"
  AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/user.pwd
  Require valid-user

  RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} !^$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your-project-domain.com/zone?user=%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}   [P,L]
</Location>
```

It will set a basic auth protected location `/auth/basic` that will redirect user to a specified location if authentication was successful, while saving username in GET variable.

Comment: I assume the above example  has to take place somewhere in the Apache environment?

Comment: The only thing I am sure I understand it is `zone` after the url `http://your-project-domain.com/zone` should this be the name of the application?

Comment: Yes. I named it `zone` but you can name your route whatever you like